# I want to use RestSharp for my Universal Windows App project in Visual Studio 2013 for Smartsheet API, but I get these errors

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, nuget, restsharp

**Error Message (Universal App - Windows):**

```
PM> install-package restsharp
Installing 'RestSharp 105.2.2'.
Successfully installed 'RestSharp 105.2.2'.
Adding 'RestSharp 105.2.2' to UniversalCSharpAppSmartsheet.Windows.
Uninstalling 'RestSharp 105.2.2'.
Successfully uninstalled 'RestSharp 105.2.2'.
Install failed. Rolling back...
install-package : Could not install package 'RestSharp 105.2.2'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets '.NETCore,Version=v4.5.1', but the package 
does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author.
At line:1 char:1
+ install-package restsharp
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], InvalidOperationException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PowerShell.Commands.InstallPackageCommand
```

I'm trying to use the Smartsheet API and that actually installs a version of RestSharp v105....something.  Any ways, I get the error message above only when I'm trying to set this up in a Universal Windows App.  I'm trying to get up-to-speed on this new universal thing MS is pushing.  Of all the nuget packages I've been testing out this is the only one that I'm having issues installing.  I'm not an expert with Nuget so i'm all sure what i need to do to get this to install.  I just want to use this awesome tool in my project.

**Error Message (Universal App - Windows Phone):**

I get a similiar error when i direct my package installer to the windows phone portion of the universal app solution.

```
PM> install-package restsharp
Installing 'RestSharp 105.2.2'.
Successfully installed 'RestSharp 105.2.2'.
Adding 'RestSharp 105.2.2' to UniversalCSharpAppSmartsheet.WindowsPhone.
Uninstalling 'RestSharp 105.2.2'.
Successfully uninstalled 'RestSharp 105.2.2'.
Install failed. Rolling back...
install-package : Could not install package 'RestSharp 105.2.2'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets 'WindowsPhoneApp,Version=v8.1', but the 
package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author.
At line:1 char:1
+ install-package restsharp
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], InvalidOperationException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PowerShell.Commands.InstallPackageCommand
```

The same Nuget package works just fine in any other project as long as it's not a Windows Universal App, but I don't want to make any other project like a console app, please any help would be most appreciated, thanks.

Comment: RestSharp [isn't supported in Universal Apps](https://github.com/restsharp/RestSharp/issues/530), and there are no plans to rectify this.  You can install the Portable Port if all you need is RestSharp, but if your package requires the full RestSharp Package, you'll have to use workarounds to get it to even install, and if you manage to get it to compile, you'll likely fail validation checks if you submit your app to the Windows App Store;  In short, this isn't possible.

Comment: Gotcha, thanks for the response.